# Error when trying to run a max function in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

So, I tried to write a simple function which  tells me which number is the biggest.
When it comes to min, there is no error, but with max it's kind of different for some reasons.

```
let pls a b = max a b
let r = pls 4 5

;;
```

And I get this error : 
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         'a -> 'b

Comment: What if you add `;;` at the end of the first line? When I try it out I don't get any error.

Comment: There is no need to add `;;` between definitions. The code extract works fine by itself. The error is elsewhere.

Comment: Could you paste your complete code sample? As octachron said, the current code you have, runs without error.

Comment: I run ocaml, and paste the above code, and there is no error. Please check if you wrote the actual code

Comment: I'd bet this is a "reevaluate your buffer" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is 99.9999% a problem of something you typed earlier. Like for example you played around defining a max function.

When you get strange errors in the interactive top level always try closing the top level and starting with a fresh one.

Adding ";;" after every definition as suggested in the comments can help too. Because with everything at once any error will just show the error. Processing each line by itself you get to see the type of each. For example this could happen:

```
# let pls a b = max a b;;
val pls : ('a -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a = <fun>
```

That is not the type you expect for pls and should make you investigate what `max` is defined as. Or make you restart your top level.